# Automatic video compilation AI based tool or app

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation

I am in search of an application, website, or tool that allows for the creation of video compilations based on the selected videos as input. I want to generate 60-90 seconds videos for social media based on dosens of video files I have. I don't care much about how the input videos are cut for the final video.

Most AI tools I've experimented with create entirely new graphics (no option to import your own video) or apply AI effects to existing footage, which is not what I need.

Google Photos has a feature somewhat aligned with my needs, where it can create videos based on a keyword from my video library. However, it does not allow for manual selection of specific videos. Also, its keyword functionality is limited — you cannot assign keywords to your videos yourself, and it generates the same video every time you try.

Is there a tool that allows for manual selection of specific videos and generates a new video of specific length?

Ideally, this tool would be user-friendly and designed for generating content suitable for social media platforms like Instagram.

Thank you for any suggestions.